# Disable all subtitles (softsub) in .mkv, .mp4 files

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-file, mp4, matroska

I have several Movies/Animes with many subtitles, and I want disable all (not remove) **subtitles** in a batch (`.bat` file); below current code:

```
for %%a in (*.mkv, *.mp4) do (
    REM disable subtitles
)
```

How could this be done?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Take a look here [How to disable subtitles decoding in ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12175153/3080770)

Comment: @Hackoo Your link gives a solution to *remove* the subtitles, but the OP explicitly said that it does not want to remove them, just disabling them (no subtitle with the "default" flag)

Comment: @PierU did not find any that help, ffmpeg only remove subtitles

Comment: It has to do with the `-disposition` and `-infer_no_subs` options. But in my experience it's quite tricky to use... When I'm at home I can retrieve the exact way to use them.

Answer (score 1):

In a recent past I found by trial and errors how to set/unset the default subtitle tracks on the output file.

**Same default track as in the input file:**

`-default_mode infer_no_subs`

**No default track:**

`-default_mode infer_no_subs -disposition:s -default`

or

`-default_mode infer_no_subs -disposition:s none`

**Force a default track:**

`-default_mode infer_no_subs -disposition:s:2 default` (sets the 3rd track as default)

*Note: if no option at all is coded, the 1st track is always the default track*